# Three series theorem - convergence of $\sum X_n$ with $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{n}{1+(nx^2)}$

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose X_s are independent r.v.s with densities:
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{n}{1+(nx^2)}
$$
Does the following series converge with probability 1:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty X_n
$$

Now, I've calculated the CDF to be
$$
F_n(t) = \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(nt)+\frac{1}{2}
$$

and tried using $c=1$ in Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem:
$$
\sum_{n}^{\infty}P(|X_n| > 1) =\sum_{n}^{\infty} F_n(-1) + 1 - F_n(1) = \sum_{n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(-n)+\frac{1}{2}+1-(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(n) + \frac{1}{2}) = \\
= \sum_{n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(-n)-\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(n)+1
$$

What could be done next to show this series is divergent(I already know the answer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **"What could be done next to show that this series is convergent (I already know the answer)?"**

---

The answer is "nothing can be done to show that the series converges."  It diverges.

Note that for $x>0$, $\arctan(x)=\pi/2-\arctan(1/x)$.  Thus, for $n\ge1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\arctan(-n)-\arctan(n)+\pi&=2\arctan(1/n)\\\\
&=\frac2n +O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as the harmonic series, $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$, diverges, the series of interest, $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1\pi \arctan(-n)-\frac1\pi \arctan(n)+1\right)$, diverges likewise.

Comment: Whoops! I meant diverges! :)

Comment: Indeed.   And pleased to see that this was helpful.

Comment: Yet another example why real analysis/calculus is an important tool. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.